# Integration by reduction

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to prove this formula
$$I_n = \int u^n \sqrt {a^2 - u^2} \cdot du = \frac {1}{n+2} u^{n-1} \left( a^2 - u^2 \right)^{3/2} - \frac {n-1}{n+1} a^2 I_{n-2} $$
When I integrate by parts, I get another expression
$$\hat{u}=u^{n-1} \hspace{2cm} dv=u\sqrt{a^2-u^2}$$
$$d\hat{u}=(n-1)u^{n-2} \hspace{2cm} v=-\frac{1}{3}(a^2-u^2)^{3/2}$$
Then, 
$$I_n =-\frac{1}{3} u^{n-1} \left( a^2 - u^2 \right)^{3/2} + \frac{n-1}{3}\int u^{n-2}\sqrt {a^2 - u^2}(a^2-u^2) \cdot du$$
$$I_n =-\frac{1}{3} u^{n-1} \left( a^2 - u^2 \right)^{3/2} + \frac{n-1}{3}(a^2I_{n-2}-I_{n})$$

$$I_n = -\frac {1}{n+2} u^{n-1} \left( a^2 - u^2 \right)^{3/2} + \frac {n-1}{n+2} a^2 I_{n-2} $$

Comment: It is easier to find the error, if you show the complete calculation you did.

Comment: The first term coincides - just a sign-error, the second error is more serious, so check your second integrating-by-part-step.

Comment: done.. I don't see the error